# C++ overloading * to multiply fractions of different types

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have a fraction class with private types N (numerator) and D (denominator). this is too allow the types to be of different number types. I have also made a operator function that overrides the asterisk so that I can do x*y where x and y represent fraction objects. However, unless both only use one type, it doesn't work. How can I get round this issue? tried separate template for the function but seems convoluted. In addition, if there's a way to say in templates only number types (similar to Number class in java) that would be much appreciated :)

```
using namespace std;

template <typename N, typename  D> class Fraction {
private:
    N num;
    D denom;

public:
    Fraction(N numerator = 1, D denominator = 0) {
        assert(numerator != 0);
        this -> num   =     numerator;
        this -> denom =     denominator;
    }
    inline N getNumerator()    { return num;   }
    inline D getDenominator()  { return denom; }

    void setNumerator(N numerator)      { num = numerator;      }
    void setDenominator(D denominator)  { denom = denominator;  }

    friend Fraction operator*(Fraction& f, Fraction& g) {
        N numerator;
        D denominator;
        numerator = f.getNumerator() * g.getNumerator();
        denominator = f.getDenominator() * g.getDenominator();

        return Fraction(numerator, denominator);
    }

    friend Fraction operator*(const Fraction& f, int n) {
        return Fraction(n*f.getNumerator, f.getDenominator());
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Fraction& f ) {
        return os << f.num << "/" << f.denom << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: you might be interested in [`std::ratio`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio), though its all about compile time fractions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your operator must have *four* template parameters:

```
template <typename N1, typename  D1, typename N2, typename  D2> 
Fraction<N1, D1> operator*(Fraction<N1, D1>& f, Fraction<N2, D2>& g) {
    N1 numerator;
    D1 denominator;
    numerator = f.getNumerator() * g.getNumerator();
    denominator = f.getDenominator() * g.getDenominator();

    return Fraction<N1, D1>(numerator, denominator);
}
```

(Note that there is no need to make the operator a `friend`.)

Comment: aah thank you, by any chance do you know why/how I should avoid friend in future? Use it almost all the time

Comment: Also results round down is there a way to store results accurately without forcing types?

Comment: @Rubbs: There's no rounding down in multiplication? In general, storing results "accurately" starts with an understanding of what accuracy means for your problem. No computer can contain all digits of pi, but most are accurate enough.

Comment: @Rubbs: The purpose of `friend` is to allow access to non-public members. If it doesn't need access to non-public members, then it need not be a `friend`. As for the rounding, I can't improve on @MSalters' reply.

Comment: @Rubbs: I should add that if it need not be a `friend`, then it ought not to be. Good encapsulation means not giving more access than is called for. The postman should have access to the mail slot in my front door; giving him my house keys would also work, but it would be inviting trouble.

Comment: @Rubbs if a function defined inside the class definition is declared with `friend`, it will be not only able to access the non-public members but declared as a non-member function which can be only looked-up by [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). and the latter can sometimes avoid the name pollution and ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class N, class D=N>
class Fraction {
    N numerator = 0;
    D denominator = 1;

    constexpr Fraction& operator*=(Fraction const& rhs)&{
      numerator *= rhs.numerator;
      denominator *= rhs.denominator;
      return *this;
    }
    constexpr Fraction& operator*=(int rhs)&{
      numerator *= rhs;
      return *this;
    }
    template<class N2, class D2>
    constexpr Fraction& operator*=(Fraction<N2, D2> const& rhs)&{
      numerator *= rhs.numerator;
      denominator *= rhs.denominator;
      return *this;
    }
    friend constexpr Fraction operator*(Fraction lhs, Fraction const& rhs) {
      lhs*=rhs;
      return std::move(lhs);
    }
    template<class N2, class D2>
    friend constexpr Fraction operator*(Fraction lhs, Fraction<N2,D2> const& rhs) {
      lhs*=rhs;
      return std::move(lhs);
    }

    friend constexpr Fraction operator*(Fraction lhs, int rhs) {
      lhs*=rhs;
      return std::move(lhs);
    }
    friend constexpr Fraction operator*(int lhs, Fraction rhs) {
      rhs*=lhs;
      return std::move(rhs);
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Fraction& f ) {
        return os << f.numerator << "/" << f.denominator << endl;
    }
};
// deduction guide.  If you are mixing types, you have to pass in
// the type explicitly.  This is intentional.
template<class T>
Fraction(T, T)->Fraction<T,T>;
```

here is a decent implementation of what you are trying to do.

The lack of accessors is intentional; that is pointless boilerplate here.  And the default Fraction is `0/1` not `1/0`.

The non-template operators are useful, because they permit

```
Fraction x{5,2};
x *= {2,3};
auto y = x*{1,2};
```

and the like.

This design is a bit future proof, and is a good default pattern to follow when writing arithmetic types.  It isn't perfect (it doesn't support using deduced types for the result of `a*b`), but it solves a bunch of problems you don't know you have.

Suppose `N` or `D` are some kind of bigint (stored on the heap, but move-efficient); then the above construct will permit long chains of `*` to occur without reallocating; it will reuse the temporary buffer repeatedly "for free".

```
Fraction<BigInt> a,b,c,d,e;
auto r = a*b*c*d*e;
```

`a*b` copies `a`, then does multiplication, then moves the result, then does `*c` without a copy, then does `*d` without a copy, then does `*e` without a copy, then stores that original modified copy of `a` in `r`.

The `constexpr` spam is because doing fraction math at compile time is a reasonable thing to want to do.

Comment: What does the deduction guide do? Never seen that before :0

Comment: and why class in template rather than typename?

Comment: @Rubbs: The deduction guides allow you to write `Fraction x{5,2};` instead of `Fraction<int,int> x{5,2};`. As for the `class` in template, that's personal preference.

Comment: I can already do that? Or is this important if you define a constructor as explicit?

Comment: @Rubbs Implicit deduction guilds are added.  As I personally consider the risk of accidentally making a non-uniform fraction to be worth avoiding, I blocked that; the only guide requires that numerator and denominator types match.  When you want different types, you can do it, but you have to be explicit.  Too many surprising things happen when you work on non-uniform types of numbers in my experience to make that silent.